# Can another site use my PHP script externally?

Tags: php

So I make some basic PHP software and have a config file. The file contains database information only, there are no user passwords etc etc. However, I declare the variables just as normal ($test = "test";), and was wondering if someone could use require/include to get the variables? I think they wouldn't be able to access the variables with file_get_contents(); due to the way PHP works. But I'm not sure about require/include. Obviously you can do it locally, but what about from other sites?

Example to clear things up:

http://example.com/config.php

- $db_host
- $db_user
- $db_pass
- $db_base

Now with http://anotherexample.com/somepage.php would they be able to use require/include to fetch the PHP script from example.com and then echo the variables?

Thanks!

Comment: no, not unless your server is badly configured. your server would EXECUTE the script and the only thing the outsider would get is your script's OUTPUT. e.g. go hit ANY php page on the web, do a view source - you will not see the php source code, you'll see only the html that the php produced.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I know PHP is ran by the server, not the client, but I'm not the most advanced person in PHP and wanted to check I didn't have any security vulnerabilities :P

Comment: of course, that's not saying that your server couldn't leak the source. e.g. you mess up a .conf file setting and turn off php, now your server WILL send out the raw .php source, since it has no idea how to execute it. generally speaking, you probably SHOULD put sensitive stuff like db connection variables into files that are kept outside your document root. even if php gets killed somehow, the files would not be accessible via http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you file is a PHP file, and the configurations are PHP code, and your server is setup to correctly run .php files through the PHP processor...then, only people within the same server could potentially require or include the file.  There are some basic PHP base directory configurations, etc., and some "safe mode" features that will prohibit users on shared servers from being able to do this--so long as it's setup correctly.

Other than on a shared server that's not configured to protect your directory from other users on that same server...about the only way the file can get compromised is if Apache stops recognizing the file extension and serves it to the web browser as plain text, etc...which is also a configuration issue.

Comment: Because the potential danger of servers stopping to process the script files and instead sending their source code (thus revealing stored secret information) is present, people started putting stuff that should never ever be served via HTTP outside of the "DOCUMENT_ROOT" directory.